# Проблема с status code 500

Tags: php, javascript

Есть проект, клиенская часть запущена на localhost/8080, серверная(php) на localhost. Проблема в том, что при api запросах

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
users:1  Failed to load http://localhost/app/getUsersFromApp/asdas: Response to preflight
request doesn't pass access control check: No
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed
access. The response had HTTP status code 500.
```

Фронтенд работает на `vue` запросы отправляю через `axios`

Уже перепробовал, наверное, все советы из интернета, не помогает, поэтому вопрос такой. Я так понял, что между `http://localhost:8080` и `http://localhost` нужно писать `cross domain` запрос, почемуто, но, так как в конечном итоге фронтенд и бекенд будут работь на одном домене в интернете, такой проблемы не будет(я так понял). Можно ли как-то запустить на `locachost` `vue cli` и `php` так, что бы считался как один домен, и небыло неоходимости писать настройки `cross`.

Comment: Если собираете vue через webpack, то настройте proxyTable

Comment: У вас случайно не Linux?

Comment: Windows 7 у меня